# PHP Json Encode array

Tags: php, arrays, json

I've got some Json being generated from PHP but I cannot seem to get it to be the format that I need.

```
$metas = get_post_meta( $key, '_tribe_tickets_meta', TRUE ); 
foreach ( $metas as $metakey ){
        $metaarray[] = array('seat_id' => $metakey);
    }
}
$array1 = array(
'bookings',
array($metaarray
),  
);
$jsonSave = json_encode($array1);
```

This gives me this output

```
["bookings",[[{"seat_id":"C_22"},{"seat_id":"BB_10"}]]]
```

What I am trying to achieve is this.

```
{"bookings":[{"seat_id":"C_22"}, {"seat_id":"BB_10"}]}
```

Thanks in advance for help, I'm entirely new to Json.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace:

```
$array1 = array('bookings',array($metaarray));
```

With the following

```
$array1 = ['bookings'=>$metaarray];
```

Answer (score 2):

then you need to use associative array, like:

```
$array1 = array('bookings' => $metaarray);
```

when using associative array, you will get the right json formating.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this as well

```
$array1['bookings']=array($metaarray);
$jsonSave = json_encode($array1);
```